# Limpiar @Html.EditorFor con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hola tengo la siguiente vista; hace todo correcto pero al momento de darle **Guardar** los campos no se limpian, siguen teniendo la información anterior.

[image]

Mi duda es ¿cómo le puedo hacer mediante `JavaScript` para que al momento de que el usuario le de guardar las veces que el quiera, se limpien los campos?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.btnSave').click(function (event) {
    $("#txtCourseID")[0].reset();
});
```

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NombreOperacion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id= "txtCourseID" } })
```

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo del formulario por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el ejemplo de tu pregunta, lo que te interesa "resetear" es el `@Html.EditorFor`.

Prueba esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.btnSave').click(function (event) {
     $("#txtCourseID").val("");
  });
  // ...
</script>
```

Y cambia el `@Html.EditorFor` por un `@Html.TextBoxFor`, de la siguiente manera:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NombreOperacion, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtCourseID" } )
```

Comment: Ya lo intente y tampoco funciona, no limpia el @Html.EditorFor

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el `@Html.EditorFor` por un `@Html.TextBoxFor`. La respuesta está editada y modificada, consúltala por favor.

Comment: De esa manera si funciono, muchas gracias! por tu ayuda